# I have same number in excel i need to group multiple groups from smallest to largest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Have a excel in where data present in each row in following way:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Where I need to order in a such a way:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

How can I sort in above way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula:

`=TOROW(WRAPCOLS(A1:I1,3))`

where 3 represents the number of repeats

Answer (score 3):

### Sequences

- Ike's answer says it all.
- To dig in deeper, you could ask yourself how to acquire the **initial** sequence in the first place. A simple way to do it (`A1`) would be with:

  ```
  =TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(,3),{1;2;3}))
  ```

[image]

- Similarly, you could acquire the **required** sequence (`A2`) with:

  ```
  =TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(,3),{1;2;3}),,1)
  ```
- Observe the different results by modifying the numbers in the formulas.
- Note that you can do the same for columns by using `TOCOL` instead of `TOROW`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the present edit of the post, OP needs the following formulas if they are using `MS365` that said,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(WRAPROWS(A1:A9,3),,1)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=SORTBY(A1:A9,MAP(A1:A9,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,INDEX(A1:A9,1),COUNTIF(x:y,x)))))
```

---

Comment: hmm - the edit wasn't done by OP ... in the text it still says "where data present in each **row**"

Comment: The edit is not done by OP but the edit is done correctly by @Dominique since the OP says _I Have a excel in where data present in each row in following way:_ **in each row**, so OP means to say, the data is by row for each of those numbers and not the whole segment. Hence why the statement is used and formula is proposed however latest post by OP clears that all thanks