# Want to group based on certain row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a set of data as below in Excel

[image]

Want to group or sort based on below

[image]

I have large set of data where i need to sort based on above

Comment: Sort by Rate column

Comment: Here I have given sample rate, where as rate might differ in original document. My idea is grouping should be done based on first entry of user1,2 and 3. Then second entry of user1,2 and 3 similarly need to do all the available rows

Comment: What is your Excel Version? are you using Excel 2010?

Comment: Using office 365 enterprise edition version 2310

Comment: So do you need the output in `Structured References`?

Comment: Yes, basically i have 10000 users with 70 rows for each of them. I need to group first row of user1 to 70 in first 70 rows, then second row of each user in 71 to 140th row and so on.

Comment: See below i have posted an answer!

Comment: How is this question different than this previous one you asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528012/i-have-same-number-in-excel-i-need-to-group-multiple-groups-from-smallest-to-lar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `MS365` the following formula should work, however the formula wont work if the output is needed in structured references:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SORTBY(Table_1,MAP(Table_1[User],LAMBDA(x,LET(y,INDEX(Table_1[User],1),COUNTIF(x:y,x)))))
```

---

Also I had prefer using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow this simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date 1", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"User"}, {{"All", each _, type table [User=text, Emp=number, Rate 1=number, Date 1=nullable date, Rate 2=number, Rate 3=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"User", "Emp", "Rate 1", "Date 1", "Rate 2", "Rate 3", "Index"}, {"User", "Emp", "Rate 1", "Date 1", "Rate 2", "Rate 3", "Index"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}, {"User", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Or, in a simpler way could be using a helper column and add the following formula to sort on:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX([User],1):[@User],[@User])
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot will check the same in our sheet. Hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all users have `n` number of occurances:

```
=LET(n,MAX(COUNTIF(Table1[Emp],Table1[Emp])),
SORTBY(Table1,
       TOCOL(SEQUENCE(,n,,n)+SEQUENCE(n,,0,1))))
```